# Fabric JS Unicode Issue

Tags: fabricjs

We are using Fabric JS (4.1.0) and noticed that special characters like ! or @ are not pulling through to the text object in the canvas. They are simply showing as space characters but normal alphabet characters come through as expected.

I've collated the below script to grab the unicode of a string and return it back as a unicode string. Running the function below returns the exact unicode data we expect however, when passing the variable of the unicode string to it, the \u2702 text simply shows, however if I pass the same value in "hardcoded" like the commented out part it renders as expected.

Why is this happening and how can we fix it?

```
function unicodeEscape(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\s\S]/g, function(character) {
        var escape = character.charCodeAt().toString(16),
            longhand = escape.length > 2;

     longhand = true;


        return '\\' + (longhand ? 'u' : 'x') + ('0000' + escape).slice(longhand ? -4 : -2);
    });
 }


canvas.clear();
var encodedVal = unicodeEscape('✂');
console.log(encodedVal);
text = new fabric.Text(encodedVal);
canvas.add(text);

//    Function call that works perfectly and renders the element:
// text = new fabric.Text("\u2702");
// canvas.add(text);
```

Comment: Hello, What version of fabric are you using? Because I have no problem with "!", "@" or with emojis

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not pulling through to the text data", but it's unlikely that Fabric is the culprit. If your strings are being sent to a database you may just be using the wrong datatype in your table. Your server endpoint may also be stripping out special characters. It's impossible to know without more information.

Comment: Please share a fiddle or a working snippet showing the issue (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This serves two purposes. 1. it lets us test out your code 2. creating a minimal example to demonstrate an issue isolates the problem from the rest of your code and will often show you that the issue is in your application itself.